# What does scaffolding mean in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, scaffolding

I'm coming back to programming with Laravel by reading the documentation in the official website. Now I realized there is a 5.0 version and I'm trying it, but by I've noticed something called "scaffolding for user registration and authentication" and I don't understand it at all.

Maybe it's because my main language is Spanish and that word doesn't make sense for me in this context, but I'm really confused.

In the website, the paragraph says this:

> Laravel ships with scaffolding for user registration and authentication. If you would like to remove this scaffolding, use the fresh Artisan command:
>
> ```
> php artisan fresh
> ```

So I would like to know what does it exactly mean and what does it stand for.

Comment: you can find your answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235018/what-is-scaffolding-is-it-a-term-for-a-particular-platform

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The term `Scaffolding` roughly aims to a quickly set up skeleton for an app or your project.

The main purpose of Scaffolding is to speed your workflow rather than creating it new.

Here is the [JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) for your reference.

If you don't want you shall use `php artisan fresh` as you said in your question.

To get the generator back from your composer

```
composer require laracasts/generators --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007535/1476885) in another question, I believe that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29) provides a narrow and restricted view. Scaffolding is **not** just for CRUD operations on top of a database. Scaffolding has a broader objective to give you a skeleton app for **any kind** of technology.

[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) is a modern and useful tool for **scaffolding**. Using their own words:

> ## The web's scaffolding tool for modern webapps
>
> **What's Yeoman?**
>
> Yeoman helps you to kickstart new projects, prescribing best practices
>   and tools to help you stay productive.
>
> To do so, we provide a generator ecosystem. A generator is basically a
>   plugin that can be run with the `yo` command to scaffold complete
>   projects or useful parts.
>
> Through our official Generators, we promote the "Yeoman workflow".
>   This workflow is a robust and opinionated client-side stack,
>   comprising tools and frameworks that can help developers quickly build
>   beautiful web applications. We take care of providing everything
>   needed to get started without any of the normal headaches associated
>   with a manual setup.
>
> With a modular architecture that can scale out of the box, we leverage
>   the success and lessons learned from several open-source communities
>   to ensure the stack developers use is as intelligent as possible.
>
> As firm believers in good documentation and well thought out build
>   processes, Yeoman includes support for linting, testing, minification
>   and much more, so developers can focus on solutions rather than
>   worrying about the little things.

That's it. Use scaffolding to create a quick-start application to work as an example or the foundation of your solution. It makes you productive faster them building things from scratch.